# Prove the inequality $0 \leq e^{-nx} - (1-x)^n \leq nx^2 e^{-nx}$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

This inequality appeared in a print publication:

> $$0 \le e^{-nx} - (1-x)^n \le nx^2 e^{-nx} \qquad (0 \le x \le 1)$$

No conditions on $n$ were stated but it's probably safe to take $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm specifically interested in proving the right-hand portion of the result. Differentiation produced inconvenient expressions; however, maybe I made bad choices of functional form. Would series expansion be the preferred approach here?

Comment: can you give us a link of such publication?

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ps/1180728778  (page 152, middle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $1-x \le e^{-x}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Hence, $(1-x)^n \le e^{-nx}$, i.e. $0 \le e^{-nx}-(1-x)^n$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Also, since the map $y \to ny^{n-1}$ is non-decreasing on $[0,1] \supseteq [1-x,e^{-x}]$, we have $$e^{-nx}-(1-x)^n = \int_{1-x}^{e^{-x}}ny^{n-1}dy \le \int_{1-x}^{e^{-x}}n(e^{-x})^{n-1}dy  = ne^{-(n-1)x}[e^{-x}-(1-x)] = ne^{-nx}[1-(1-x)e^x].$$

For $x \in [0,1]$, we have $e^x \ge 1+x$ and $1-x \ge 0$. Hence, $1-(1-x)e^x \le 1-(1-x)(1+x) = x^2$.

Therefore, $e^{-nx}-(1-x)^n \le ne^{-nx}[1-(1-x)e^x] \le nx^2e^{-nx}$, which is the desired upper bound.

Comment: It seems you are making the assumption, in the limits of your first integral and in the subsequent inequality, that $e^{-x}\ge1-x$. While this is true, and the basis of the left hand inequality from the question, since it *is* part of the question, and not answered anywhere in the question, it would be nice to mention that it is being assumed.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $e^x\ge1+x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

We also have Bernoulli's Inequality: $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$ for $x\ge-1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

First we have
$$
e^{-x}\ge1-x\implies e^{-nx}\ge(1-x)^n\tag{1}
$$
Next we have
$$
\begin{align}
e^x\ge1+x
&\implies e^x(1-x)\ge\left(1-x^2\right)\tag{2}\\
&\implies e^{nx}(1-x)^n\ge\left(1-x^2\right)^n\ge1-nx^2\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
(1-x)^n\ge e^{-nx}\left(1-nx^2\right)\tag{4}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(4)$, we get
$$
e^{-nx}\ge(1-x)^n\ge e^{-nx}\left(1-nx^2\right)\tag{5}
$$
which is equivalent to your inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $e^{nx}$ positive for any $n,x$

Inequality becomes 
$$0\leq 1-e^{n x} (1-x)^n\leq n x^2$$
Derivative of $f(x)=1-e^{n x} (1-x)^n$ is

$f'(x)=\dfrac{n x e^{n x} (1-x)^n}{1-x}$

as $0\leq x \leq 1$ we have $f'(x)\geq 0$ so we know that $f(x)$ is increasing and its maximum on $[0;\;1]$ is attained at $x=1$

Even at its maximum we have

$0\leq 1-e^{1n } (1-1)^n\leq 1^2n$ that is $0\leq 1\leq n$ therefore, assuming $n\geq 1$, we have 
$$0\leq 1-e^{n x} (1-x)^n\leq n x^2, \text{ for any }x\in [0;\;1]\text{ and }n\ge 1$$

Comment: What does the derivative of $f$ tell us about $1-e^{nx}(1-x)^n\le nx^2$?

Comment: @robjohn I needed to prove that $f(x)$ is increasing in $[0,1]$ to be sure that even at its maximum it was smaller than the RHS

Comment: But both $f(x)$ and $nx^2$ are increasing. I don't see where you show that $f(x)\le nx^2$ anywhere but at $x=1$.

Comment: @robjohn $x$ is in $[0,1]$ therefore $nx^2$ is $n$ as maximum. Please read my answer carefully... :)

Comment: $x$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ and attains its maximum at $x=1$ and at $x=1$, we have that $x\le nx^2$. However, it is not the case that $x\le nx^2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.