# Prove that $e^{-ax} \leq (1 - x)^a + ax^2/2$ for $a > 1$, $0 \le x \le 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, elementary-functions

> Here we assume that all variables are reals. I would like to show that
> $$
> e^{-ax} \leq (1 - x)^{a} + \frac{1}{2} ax^2 \tag{1}
> $$
> for all $a > 1$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

By Taylor’s theorem, I know that, in order to show that (1), it suffices to show that
$$
(a - 1)(1 - \theta)^{a - 2} - a e^{-a \theta} + 1 \geq 0 \tag{2}
$$
for all $a > 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$. But it does not seem so easy to show (2). If we continue to calculate higher derivatives by $\theta$ of the left hand side of (2), we have to consider separately the cases of the values of $a$. It seems to me that my solution is complicated. It would be appreciated if you could give me a proof of either (1) or (2).

Comment: I found a similar but a little bit weaker inequality with a proof. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logarithm, it suffices to prove that
$$f(x) := \ln \left((1 - x)^{a} + \frac{1}{2} ax^2\right) + ax \ge 0.$$

We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{ax(ax + 2 - 2(1-x)^{a-1})}{ax^2 + 2(1-x)^a} \ge 0 \tag{1}$$
where we use $2 - 2(1-x)^{a-1} \ge 0$ since $a > 1$ and $x\in [0, 1]$.

Also, $f(0) = 0$. Thus, we have $f(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1]$.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for your pointing out incorrect argument last time. This time I did follow calculation by hand and I am now convinced that your solution is correct.

Comment: @KazuneTakahashi Thanks for verifying.

Comment: Congratulations to River Li who got the right idea. Another way to prove that $h(x,a)=ax+2-2(1-x)^{a-1}>0$ for all $0<x<1,$ $a>1$ is to observe that $h(x,1)=x>0$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}h(x,a)=x-2(1-x)^{a-1}\log(1-x)>0$ since $\log(1-x)<0.$

Comment: @GérardLetac Thanks. Can we use $2 \ge 2(1 - x)^{a-1}$ to obtain the inequality directly?

Comment: Oh, yes! Sometimes one feels completely stupid.

Comment: @GérardLetac Agree. I did not realize that it is obvious.